# terraform for_each and count logic not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm trying to create an optional HTTP listener on an app load balancer in AWS via Terraform using count and a bool value but when running the Terraform plan/apply it doesn't seem to detect it. It's as if the code does not exist. I've tried substituting the [*] value with [1] and [0] but this did not make a difference.

If I remove the [*] and then run terraform plan/apply i get the below error:

> ╷ │ Error: Missing resource instance key │  │   on lb.tf line 43, in
> resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener_http": │   43:
> target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group_http.arn │  │
> Because aws_lb_target_group.target_group_http has "count" set, its │
> attributes must be accessed on specific instances. │  │ For example,
> to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use: │
> aws_lb_target_group.target_group_http[count.index] ╵ ERRO[0004]
> Terraform invocation failed in
> /Users/frazmahmud/my_repos/post_office/poets-infra-terraform/environments/dev-appmod/elb/.terragrunt-cache/b6GHCsKU1PWUJDZv0wcBNaAJ-aw/EL5rIjZt6v1g8JksiQ9RcMOXNyk
> prefix=[/Users/frazmahmud/my_repos/post_office/poets-infra-terraform/environments/dev-appmod/elb]
> ERRO[0004] 1 error occurred:  * exit status 1

If I replace the [*] with [count.index] per above message then I receive the following error:

> ╷ │ Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context │  │   on lb.tf
> line 43, in resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener_http": │   43:
> target_group_arn =
> aws_lb_target_group.target_group_http[count.index].arn │  │ The
> "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" │
> blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set. ╵ ERRO[0004]
> Terraform invocation failed in
> /Users/frazmahmud/my_repos/post_office/poets-infra-terraform/environments/dev-appmod/elb/.terragrunt-cache/b6GHCsKU1PWUJDZv0wcBNaAJ-aw/EL5rIjZt6v1g8JksiQ9RcMOXNyk
> prefix=[/Users/frazmahmud/my_repos/post_office/poets-infra-terraform/environments/dev-appmod/elb]
> ERRO[0004] 1 error occurred:  * exit status 1

I have included the configuration below. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**main.tf**

```
// load balancer
resource "aws_lb" "load-balancer" {
  name                       = var.name
  internal                   = var.internal
  load_balancer_type         = var.load_balancer_type
  security_groups            = [aws_security_group.elb_sg.id]
  subnets                    = var.subnets
  enable_deletion_protection = var.deletion_protection
  tags                       = var.tags
}

// listener & target group - HTTPS
resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener_https" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.load-balancer.arn
  port              = var.listener_https
  protocol          = var.protocol_https
  ssl_policy        = var.ssl_policy
  certificate_arn   = var.ssl_cert

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group_https.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group_https" {
  name        = "${var.name}-https-tg"
  port        = var.listener_https
  protocol    = var.protocol_https
  target_type = var.target_type
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
}

// listener & target group - HTTP
resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener_http" {
  for_each          = toset(local.create_http_listener)
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.load-balancer.arn
  port              = var.listener_http
  protocol          = var.protocol_http

  dynamic "default_action" {
    for_each = var.create_http_listener ? [1] : []
    content {
        type             = "forward"
        target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group_http[0].arn
    }
  }

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group_http" {
  count       = var.create_http_listener ? 1 : 0
  name        = "${var.name}-http-tg"
  port        = var.listener_http
  protocol    = var.protocol_http
  target_type = var.target_type
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
}
```

**locals.tf**

```
locals {
  create_tgw_attach    = var.create_tgw_attach == true ? [var.environment] : []
  create_http_listener = var.create_http_listener == true ? [var.environment] : []
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "create_http_listener" {
  description = "is a http listener and target group required"
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}
```

Comment: Yup, if you want to use splat expression or `count.index` your target group resource has to have it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the existence of `aws_lb_target_group` depends on the following condtions:

```
var.create_http_listener ? 1 : 0
```

in every place in the code when you are using `aws_lb_target_group`, you have to check for that condition, since you can't use something that does not exist.

So your `default_action` has to be **conditional**:

```
  dynamic "default_action" {
    for_each = var.create_http_listener ? [1] : []
    content {
        type             = "forward"
        target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group_https[0].arn
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. So I've replaced the default_action block inside the resource "aws_lb_listener.listener_http" with the one in your answer (removing the trailing 's' in https as i think was a typo) and set the bool value to 'true' but it hasn't detected the change. What am i doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: @BigRed247 Not sure what "change" are you referring to? So what exactly is happening? Any new errors?

Comment: I have updated the main.tf file in the post above based on what i understood of your recommendation. So if you look at the "aws_lb_listener" resource type for resource name "listener_http", i have removed the original default action and replaced it with the dynamic default action. I am not receiving an error but it does not seem to detect any new resources when i set the bool value for "create_http_listener" to true and run terraform plan/apply.

Comment: @BigRed247 If the rule already exist, then it won't be recreated.

Comment: hi @Marcin, yes - still a little unclear on the fix here.